# Posting to Microsoft bot telegram channel return error 400

Tags: botframework, telegram

When I post a message to my Microsoft bot using Postman, the message is sent to my Skype. When I post the message to Telegram channel, I get error message 400 Bad Request (The request cannot be fulfilled due to bad syntax. The following is post body.

{

```
    "type": "message",
    "locale": "en-Us",
    "channelID":"telegram", 

    "from": {
    "id": "28:01a4752e-6cb0-459f-b94f-.....",
    "name": "bot"
    },
    "recipient": {
    "id": "29:1rNJPaNGCMPithEDVjoN00SU5S6fG......",
    "name": "My name"
    },
    "conversation": {
    "id": "29:1rNJPaNGCMPithEDVjoN00SU5S6fGZ"
    },

    "channelData":
    {
         "method": "sendMessage",
         "parameters":
         {

             "text": "This message is HTMLformatted.",
             "parse_mode": "HTML"

         }
    }
```

}